# which one was first run, usersetup.mel or userSetup.py?

Tags: python, scripting, 3d, maya, mel

[usersetup.mel-and-userSetup.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1I380.jpg)

I work with MAYA software.
I have two files, usersetup.mel and userSetup.py, which of the two files will be run first? Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Hi there, please give more details as your question is quite confusing. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I work with MAYA software, I want to create a "callback" with the help of usersetup.mel or userSetup.py, but I am confused, if I create two usertsetup.mel and userSetup.py files, which MAYA software will run first?, thanks

Comment: I suppose you could simply add a print command to both of them and see which is printed first. As much as I know the userSetup.py is called very early in during startup. At a time where the UI is not yet loaded. I think the mel version runs later.

Comment: Thank you very much, after I tried it turned out that userSetup.py was run first.